# How to easily view Failed Request Logs?

Tags: iis-7, log-files

I had hoped I could just view the XML files in IE, but I get the following error:

"Security settings do not allow the execution of script code within this stylesheet."

I don't think I've done anything special to my setup.  What is the intended way to easily view these logs out of the box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

Adding "about:internet" to the list of trusted sites in Internet Explorer should fix it.
(from this [forums post](http://forums.iis.net/t/1147605.aspx))

---

Select "Internet Options" from the IE "Tools" menu. Select the "Advanced" tab, and scroll down to Security and check the box "Allow active content to run in files on My Computer" and click the "Apply" button.

Comment: See my updated answer.